# Using "now" with the past tense

Tags: past-tense, idiomatic-language, spoken-english, sequence-of-tenses, present-perfect-progressive

I'm confused because I think the use of word "now" is kind of idiomatic in phrase 1, but on the other hand I think it should be as phrase 2.
So, is it normal to use "now" with the past simple ????

1-Your sound disappeared and came back now .

2-Your sound disappeared and has come back now.